# SML list option recusion; how to use recursion to output a SOME list

Tags: string, list, recursion, sml

Currently, my code takes in a string `s` and a string list `sl` and returns a string list where `s` was removed (once)

```
fun all_except_option (s, sl) =
    case sl of
    [] => []
      | hd::tl = if same_string(s, hd)
          then tl
          else hd::all_except_option(s, tl)
```

However, what I want is to return `NONE` if the string `s` is not in the list and if it is, return `SOME (`output of the current function`)`. However, I can't simply add `SOME(` before `hd::all_except_option(s, tl)` since `hd` will be appended to something that outputs an option and I can't figure how to do it.

Edit: thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fun all_except_option (s, ss) =
    case ss of
      [] => NONE
    | s'::ss' =>
        if s = s' then SOME ss' else
        case all_except_option (s, ss') of
          NONE => NONE
        | SOME ss'' => SOME (s'::ss')
```

Note that this only removes the first occurrence of `s`, which mirrors your version.

You can also use `Option.map` to avoid the nested case:

```
fun all_except_option (s, ss) =
    case ss of
      [] => NONE
    | s'::ss' =>
        if s = s' then SOME ss'
        else Option.map (fn ss' => s'::ss') (all_except_option (s, ss'))
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need a new function:

```
fun some_option(s,sl) = SOME( all_except_option(s, sl) )
```

Well, not quite that, as it doesn't handle the case where `all_except_option` returns `[]`, but I'll leave that as an exercise.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
case all_except_option(s, tl) of ...
```

to match the two different cases and handle each in the appropriate way.

Answer (score 0):

Andreas Rossberg provided two complete examples.

Here is a variation where the pattern matching is in the argument of the function instead:

```
fun curry f x y = f (x, y)

fun all_except_option (s, []) = NONE
  | all_except_option (s, t::ts) =
      if s = t
      then SOME ts
      else Option.map (curry op:: t) (all_except_option (s, ts))
```

Where `curry op:: t` is the function that takes a list and puts `t` in front of it:

```
- curry op:: "x" ["y", "z"];
> val it = ["x", "y", "z"] : string list
```

and is equivalent to `fn ss' => t::ss'`.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are struggling too much like me and took too much to solve that question from the course, here is a solution for you that you can simply understand:

```
(* string * string list -> string list option *)
(* Eliminate a specific string from a list of string*)
(* fun all_except_option (s, los) = [] *) (* stub *)
fun all_except_option (exc, los) =
    let
         fun all_except_option_acc (los, acc, f) = 
               case los of
                  [] => if f
                            then SOME acc
                            else NONE
               |  s::los' =>  if same_string (s, exc)
                                 then all_except_option_acc(los', acc,    true)
                                 else all_except_option_acc(los', s::acc, f)
    in
        all_except_option_acc(los,[], false)
    end
```